# Are AF improvements firmware specific or model specific?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, firmware, nikon-z6

I was checking reviews of Nikon Z6 II Autofocus capabilities. Few reviewers complained about AF not that great whereas few reviewers say that it is better after firmware update.

Are auto-focus improvements more of a software upgrade and patched through firmware or only a model change can fix any issues ?

Is there any possibility that Nikon improves AF in Z6 II through firmware ?

Comment: While I'm aware it's a different camera, the core of the answer is the same: "can a firmware upgrade improve contrast detection auto focus? probably yes, contrast detection is mostly software."

Comment: @PhilipKendall A lot has changed since then. Canon reps have said some fairly recent models are too hardware limited to be able to run the updated AF software running in even several tiers lower new models. The 2020 R5 (a 45MP $3900 camera) has a more limited processor than the newer 2022 R6 Mark II (a 24 MP $2,600 camera) and the 2023 EOS R8 (a 24 MP $1,500 camera). They're all running DiG!C X processors, but apparently DiG!C X is a "family" of processors with similar architecture, not a specific CPU. So sometimes hardware limits do affect what firmware can run on them.

Comment: As AI becomes more and more a part of AF routines, the computing power needed to run them increases dramatically. On the other hand, current market conditions makes competition for ILC sales more intense than it has been since the early 2000s. Thus, while improvements via firmware updates, other than to fix bugs, was limited more by marketing decisions ("if you want the better capability, buy the next model"), more recently manufacturers are more willing to give firmware updates to maintain competitiveness with other sellers but hardware limitations now play a larger role.